# get requests is not loading in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, urllib

I am trying to get data from the following website. https://www1.nseindia.com/products/dynaContent/common/productsSymbolMapping.jsp?symbol=SBIN&segmentLink=3&symbolCount=2&series=EQ&dateRange=+&fromDate=01-01-2020&toDate=31-12-2020&dataType=PRICEVOLUMEDELIVERABLE

I tried the following:

1. Get the whole url in requests:

```
response = requests.get('https://www1.nseindia.com/products/dynaContent/common/productsSymbolMapping.jsp?symbol=SBIN&segmentLink=3&symbolCount=2&series=EQ&dateRange=+&fromDate=01-01-2020&toDate=31-12-2020&dataType=PRICEVOLUMEDELIVERABLE')
```

2. Get the base webpage and add the params:

```
response = requests.get('https://www1.nseindia.com/products/dynaContent/common/productsSymbolMapping.jsp', params = {'symbol':'SBIN','segmentLink':'3','symbolCount':'2','series':'EQ','dateRange':' ','fromDate':'01-01-2020','toDate':'31-12-2020','dataType':'PRICEVOLUMEDELIVERABLE'})
```

3. used the urllib:

```
f = urllib.request.urlopen('https://www1.nseindia.com/products/dynaContent/common/productsSymbolMapping.jsp?symbol=SBIN&segmentLink=3&symbolCount=2&series=EQ&dateRange=+&fromDate=01-01-2020&toDate=31-12-2020&dataType=PRICEVOLUMEDELIVERABLE')
```

none of the above methods work.
They are just loading indefinitely.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When I open the link, it says GET method not authorized

Comment: Set the user agent header of a commonly used browser!

Comment: check your url... seems you have www1 instead of www

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't forget to add User-Agent to request header, like that:

```
header = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:65.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/65.0',
        "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"
    }
response = requests.get('you_url', headers=header)
print(response)
```